# Android: persisting data across app lifecycle

Tags: android, android-asynctask, singleton, persistence, instance

I'm working on an Android app that uses some background tasks (AsyncTasks) and I want to use best practices regarding data persistence across app lifecycle and tasks callbacks.

Up to now, I have a mix of practices regarding this:

1) I have some static fields in classes where AsyncTasks are used in the form of:

```
private static String str1;
private static String str2;
private static int int1;
...//=>no more than 6 static fields
```

2) I use a sinleton App instance with many getters/setters in the form of:

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx

import xxx.xxx.xxx
...

public class AppSettings {

    private static AppSettings singleton;
    private String _field1;
    ...//=>many fields

    public void setField1(String field1) { _field1 = field1; }
    public String getField1() { return _field1; }
    ...//=>many getters/setters

    private AppSettings() {}

    public AppSettings getInstance(){
        if (instance== null) {
            synchronized(AppSettings.class) {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new AppSettings();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I definitely know that abusing of static fields is not good at all, so I decided to replace them all, but I'm not completely sure if my second approach -having an application instance in a singleton with many getters/setters- is considered a good way to go, and in case not, I would like to know about better alternatives.

Thank you very much.

Edit 1: Just to clarify.

In order for you to understand more clearly what I use my AppSettings singleton class for I'll give you two examples:

1) I use it to store app setting/configuration values (that's why the name) to be available anywhere. For example, font color, font size, whatever.

2) I use it to store temporary data/values. For example, my main activity creates a small video in the backgroung using "VideoHelper" class and called through an AsyncTask, and as video generation process needs some parameters from main activity, I use AppSettings getters/setters to send them through.

Edit 2: Better explanation of everything.

Thanks to @a_local_nobody I realized my "case of use" was not so clear so I'll add a few things more.

My AppSettings is not being used to store user settings, I use SharedPreferences for that, but instead app default configuration parameters.

To give an example, I store activities background color (and this is just an example) so if in the future I change my mind and decide to use another background color this setting (and many more) are centralized there. It's like a "container" for many default app settings.

Regarding the use of getters and setters in this app singleton class, I think I'll foloww @a_local_nobody suggestion related to define some static variables in each class and use them as needed instead of having a bunch of unrelated getters/setters globally.

Anyway, all comments are welcome.

Comment: you should try to avoid async tasks in general, as they might be deprecated soon - side note

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @a_local_nobody. I use AsyncTaks for network operations, like downloading a file or getting a token id through an api (for example), and this is mandatory, you cannot run network operations in the main thread so, what are the alternatives to AsyncTask? And why you assume it might be deprecated soon?

Comment: have a look at RxJava or Coroutines, Async tasks are fine for starting out, but apparently they will be deprecated soon-ish : https://www.xda-developers.com/asynctask-deprecate-android-11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are talking about `persisting data across app lifecycle` which, in my mind, sounds like you're looking for a `ViewModel`:

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in
>   a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive
>   configuration changes such as screen rotations.

as well as:

> The purpose of the ViewModel is to acquire and keep the information
>   that is necessary for an Activity or a Fragment. The Activity or the
>   Fragment should be able to observe changes in the ViewModel.

ViewModels form part of the MVVM design pattern, with loads of examples available online.

For more info, have a look [at the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?&gclid=CjwKCAiAwZTuBRAYEiwAcr67Of1ktoRtaTHXT46WDgLS-yi9p9Tgc4KC5fCMsye9rLUVkAP_VZ5GhRoCKJ4QAvD_BwE)

---

on a side-note, perhaps you can have a look at the [google sunflower project](https://github.com/android/sunflower) for some ideas on how to implement the new architecture components, which includes usages of `ViewModels`.

---

Also worth adding, is that what you've created with your `AppSettings` solution, is a big dependency. Various things will depend on this single object and it will be needed throughout your application, most likely. You might consider, instead of creating it like this, to rather use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) with your options, for android, probably being either [Dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger) or [Koin for kotlin](https://insert-koin.io/) (if you ever swap over to kotlin) or perhaps your own form of dependency injection without having to use these frameworks.

Hope this helps

---

Edit based on feedback from OP:

> I use it to store app setting/configuration values (that's why the
>   name) to be available anywhere. For example, font color, font size,
>   whatever.

this sounds like a better use case for [Shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), especially if these are settings defined by a user, otherwise you should be savings these into `strings.xml` etc. and making use of [localization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization)

> I use it to store temporary data/values. For example, my main activity
>   creates a small video in the background using "VideoHelper" class and
>   called through an AsyncTask, and as video generation process needs
>   some parameters from main activity, I use AppSettings getters/setters
>   to send them through.

if you have a `VideoHelper` class, you might be better off either creating a Builder design pattern for this object, or having static variables for this helper to change its functionality as you need to, if these are variables for your `VideoHelper`, then they should be located with your `VideoHelper`.

Things which change together should usually stay together.

Comment: Thank you very much @a_local_nobody, you have written down a very helpful reply with good information I'll have to checkout, as I haven't been working with ViewModels in Android yet. According to what you say, I guess that creating a ViewModel is the way to go nowadays, so I'll take my time to read and I'll most likely go that way. Anyway, please read my last edit (so you get a better idea what I'm using singleton class for) and let me know if you still think "ViewModel" is the way to go.

Comment: Thank youvery much again @a_local_nobody, very quick response. I was trying to avoid static variables as I know abusing on them is not adviceable, but according to your last response I guess having some it won't "hurt anyone", right?

Comment: you're welcome :) remember to add as much detail as possible to questions in future, because it makes a difference to our answers :D I don't think making one large static object is a good idea in terms of standards, I would rather recommend having statics moved and be placed to what they are related. `VideoHelper` should contain the variables (even static) it needs to function, that's my opinion on things as i feel this uses the clean code approach

Comment: Sorry @a_local_nobody, now I realized -because of your comment- I have not been very clear explaning my case of use. As a "last" note and regarding AppSettings, I should add that what I store are not exactly user settings (I obviously use SharedPreferences for that) but insted I store app default settings, for example, background color of main activity (let's say) so if anytime I would like app has a different background color I have all this kind of startup settings centralized there. Let me know what do you think on this, and I'll update my answer so other guys can get a better idea of all.

Comment: i would still say you should rather have a look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization for how to store these values and you can then create styles and themes with these

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202050/discussion-between-a-local-nobody-and-diego-perez).

Answer (score 2):

Your approach doesn't qualify as "best practices" in modern android development.

The recommended way of handling configuration changes is by using the new [architecture component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture): [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/images/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-lifecycle.png)

It have the property of surviving the onDestroy triggered when a configuration change occurs.

[image]

Basically, you will need to move this AppSettings code to a ViewModel.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ian Medeiros, I'll reply the same as above. You have written down a very helpful reply with good information I'll have to checkout, as I haven't been working with ViewModels in Android yet. According to what you say, I guess that creating a ViewModel is the way to go nowadays, so I'll take my time to read and I'll most likely go that way. Anyway, please read my last edit (so you get a better idea what I'm using singleton class for) and let me know if you still think "ViewModel" is the way to go.